# Richfaces: rich:select click event fails

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I am using a rich:select, which I want to repopulate when it is clicked on the page. I tried this using a4j:ajax listening for the onClick-Event, but it seems like it is never received. For testing purposes I added an alert to the control, that is shown after an unpredictable number of clicks. The code in my Backing Bean is never called.

If I change the control to h:selectOneMenu it works, but the list collapses immediately so that the users cannot select an item. Additionally the manual input is a required feature.

Code in my JSF-Page:

```
<rich:select id="auftragsIdsCombo" value="#{einsatzController.einsatz.auftrag.id}" enableManualInput="true" onclick="alert('hi')">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{einsatzController.auftragsIds}" />
    <a4j:ajax event="click" render="auftragsIdsCombo" listener="#{einsatzController.loadAuftragsIds()}"/>
</rich:select>
```

Maybe there is another way of doing this, wich I am not aware of. I just want to load the items after clicking on the Dropdownbox, so that the users can either select one or use autocompletion by typing into the control.

Regards

Comment: Why would you want the list that the client uses to select an item? It seems very odd. Explain your functional requirement to get a better solution to your problem.

Comment: The rich:select is used to select the id of a Person-object which is stored in the Database. Problem is, that there are >15000 entries in that table. If I render the select with all the ids when rendering the page, its an unnecessary slowdown. Takes about 1 second and there are several selects.
I need a solution to load the ids only when the user clicks on the select or on another user interaction like clicking on a button.